# Restrict style on cloned dom

Tags: html, css, dom, shadow-dom

I have a form, which has its own styling through CSS and JavaScript.

I have cloned a dom but I don't want styling to put affect into that cloned dom. How would i achieve it?

Example for reference:

```
<div id="main">
  <section id="sectionId"> 
  </section>
  <div id="childId">
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

Cloned dom:

```
<div id="main-cloned">
  <section id="sectionId"> 
  </section>
  <div id="childId">
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

Is shadow dom the solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.